# XML parsing in Java/Clojure - type coercion with XSDs?

Tags: java, clojure, xml-parsing

Are there any XML parsers that accept an XSD for the parsing so they know how to properly coerce the types that are parsed out?

Comment: Did you have much success with this?  I would really like to do something like this, but am struggling.  I'm wondering about doing xml -> XStream -> Java Obj -> Clojure Map, but I still think it will take considerable effort, and I'm surprised that there's not something else out there like this.

Answer (score 4):

Many parsers can validate that an XML input document conforms to an XSD, but most do not apply it any further than that.

If you use JAXB, its xjc utility can generate Java classes with fields and JAXB annotations capturing the types defined in the XSD, and  marshalling/unmarshalling via JAXB will handle the types properly.

See [this tutorial](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java/jaxb/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-using-jaxb-xjc-command/) for an example.

Apache's [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) seems to have similar capabilities.

I'm not sure either of these fully satisfies your needs, but they're the closest I can think of at the moment.